# Yum not working

Tags: centos, rhel, yum

When I try to execute yum I get this:
[image]

My guess is I need to start the Ethernet connection because I cant ping and this is what what we do with SL6.

I'm new to CentOS that is why I ask.

I've already run `service start network` but it still does not work.

#### UPDATE #1

Here's the output from `ifconfig`.

[image: ss of ifconfig output]

Comment: Do you have an actual IP address on this system? Your error has nothing to do with `yum`, rather you're not able to resolve dns names to get their corresponding IP addresses. So either you're not on the network, or your system isn't able to find a DNS server to resolve IP's from DNS hostnames.

Comment: ifconfig returns http://i.imgur.com/HvJTmnW.png

Comment: That output you're seeing shows that you have no network interface setup, so that's why you're not getting on the network. You need to get your VM so that it gets an IP address and can gain access to the network!

Comment: What VM technology are you using? VirtualBox?

Comment: VMware Workstation 10. My SL6 VM runs perfectly with the same exact configuration, same as the debian 7 VM.

Comment: OK so that tells us that your issue is likely within the VM Guest and not with your VM setup. Are you running NetworkManager as a service? I'll add details to A.

Comment: See updates in my A, check if NetworkManager is running.

Comment: What CentOS are you using 5 or 6?

Answer (score 1):

#### Network setup?

Do you have an actual IP address on this system?

Your error has nothing to do with yum, rather you're not able to resolve dns names to get their corresponding IP addresses. So either you're not on the network, or your system isn't able to find a DNS server to resolve IP's from DNS hostnames.

#### Example

```
$ ip -4 addr show 
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
    inet 192.168.1.20/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global wlp3s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN 
    inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

In the above output you can see that I have 3 network interfaces. They're numbered "1,3,4". Their names are `lo`, `wlp3s0`, and `virbr0`. My WiFi is `wlp3s0`. It has IP address 192.168.1.20.

#### DNS Servers?

If you're using NetworkManager to manage your network interfaces you can query through it, using its command line tool `nmcli`.

#### Example

```
$ nmcli dev list iface wlp3s0 | grep IP4
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         ip = 192.168.1.20/24, gw = 192.168.1.254
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.1.101
IP4.DNS[2]:                             8.8.8.8
IP4.DNS[3]:                             8.8.4.4
IP4.DNS[4]:                             208.67.222.222
IP4.DNS[5]:                             208.67.220.220
IP4.DOMAIN[1]:                          bubba.net.
```

#### Determining if NetworkManager is running?

You can use the following tool, `service`, to check.

```
$ service NetworkManager start
```

#### Starting NetworkManager

To bring up a service that isn't already running you can again use the `service` command to bring it up.

```
$ sudo service NetworkManager start
```

#### Making it permanent?

To make the NetworkManager service start from boot to boot you'll need to use another tool, `chkconfig` to set which runlevels you'd like the service to run.

```
$ chkconfig --level 345 NetworkManager on
```

Answer (score 0):

Run ifconfig to check whether you're connected to a network. Have you been able to connect to a network in the past? please be more descriptive about any errors or messages that you may be getting.

Comment: This is a fresh VM, if config gives this http://i.imgur.com/HvJTmnW.png

Comment: try--> http://extr3metech.wordpress.com/2013/05/23/configuring-network-in-centos-6-3-virtual-box-screenshots/      http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/ch-network-config.html

Answer (score 0):

You can run `system-config-network-tui` for your network.